# A record DNS, nameserver help

Tags: domains, dns

I just installed kloxo on my vps and I want to link my domain to that server...which it sort of already is...I made it connect to it via an A record. That works, like the IP is pointing to my server but how do I make a website using it. I tried adding the domain but this doesn't work

...I feel i'm not explaining this well um, on my server it asked me to create DNS template so I did I created the nameservers ns1.mydomain.com, ns2.mydomain.com

Then I added the domain to the panel

mydomain.com

I go to the folder it creates to it, but no matter the file there it wont work...any ideas?

Is there a way to possibly just not even add a domain to kloxo and just kind of treat the ip of the server as the domain? Since the A record points there anyway?

I don't intend to host another website on the server anyway...

Comment: I found a way around it. I just made the domain have a dedicated IP on the server

I followed this guide:

http://www.a2hosting.com/resource-center/kloxo-vps-setup/other-useful-features

but instead of 192.168.1.1 I put the ip I wanted to use for it and it worked

would answer but I can't for 8 hours.

Comment: I am closing this question as it does not meet the quality guidelines (see our [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information). If you have any questions about why this action was taken, please ask on [Pro Webmasters Meta](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/).